# How to combine two set of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two list as follows (both list contains super long data):

```
list_1 = ["apple", "orange", "banana", ......]
list_2 = [[1,0,0,0,0], [0.5,0,0.5,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], ......]
```

I want to have an outcome of :

```
list = {"apple" : [1,0,0,0,0], "orange" : [0.5,0,0.5,0,0], "banana" : [0,0,1,0,0], .......]
```

What I want to do is like putting list_1[0] to list_2[0], list_1[1] to list_2[1] and so on.

Is there a way to do automatically pair the data up no matter how long the datasets are ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use `zip`:

```
list = {}
for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2):
    list[x] = y
```

Comment: You can save on the loop and simply use the `dict` constructor: `dict(zip(list_1, list_2))`

Comment: For someone who doesn't know how to create a dict, it may be easier to have a comprehensive example rather than a quick one. But yes, one-liner are prettier if you know what you're doing.

Comment: It's not about being a one-liner or not. It's being simple, readable code. And for someone who doesn't know how to create a dict, it might be very useful to learn using the `dict` constructor. Just pointing out a neat little alternative. BTW, you call your dict `list` which is first of all confusing (because it is not a list) and second shadows the built-in `list`...